# WindowBuilder Crashes when tabbing design

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

Recently, I've been facing a headache problem with Eclipse WindowBuilder every time the complier parses to the code, i.e. when I move to from source to design. It gives me a long error message titled (Internal Error) so in order to enter the design tab again, I have to close the entire Eclipse. I have deleted the entire Java folder from my Mac and download it again along with Kepler IDE however the bug remains showing every time I want to use WindowBuilder.

Has anyone faced such a bug before?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, I think it improved in my case after I removed the OpenJDK that came bundled with Debian and used Sun's JDK 8 instead.